# What is the relationship name of my wife's brother to me?

Tags: kinship-terms

What is the relationship name of my wife's brother to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a word meaning "the wife of one's brother".](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12585/looking-for-a-word-meaning-the-wife-of-ones-brother)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I think..."wife of one's brother" and "brother of one's wife" are two different things, it just happens we use the same word for them in English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He is your **brother-in-law**.

There has already been a similar question posted here to which the answer was "sister-in-law", so I'll finish the list here:

Your spouse's brother *or* your sister's husband is your **brother-in-law**.

Your spouse's sister *or* your brother's wife is your **sister-in-law**.

Your spouse's father is your **father-in-law**.

Your spouse's mother is your **mother-in-law**.

Your daughter's husband is your **son-in-law**.

Your son's wife is your **daughter-in-law**.

Where applicable (and where disowning has not occurred), you child's same-sex life partner under a legal bond (whether marriage or civil union or what have you) or a bond you recognise even when the law does not would be either a son-in-law or daughter-in-law, as applicable.

Comment: Well, that's a much more thorough answer than mine, though I do quibble with the addition of "even when the law does not" as "in law" does etymologically derive from traditional common law.

Comment: @smithco: etymologically it originally meant that, but its meaning has since solidified to be essentially what’s given here, no longer depending on the law.  And I get the impression that its meaning is currently shifting — roughly but not exactly in step with the law — to include same-sex marriages .

Comment: The problem with shifting meanings is that they create confusion.  In this case, your expanded meaning of "in law" is actually the first time I have seen it used with that meaning.

Comment: It has been a long time since marriage made anybody *de jure* father, mother, brother, sister, son or daughter to anyone else (with all the rights and privileges associated with blood relationships). The "in-law" relationships are only descriptive now, not legal.

Comment: I hear "in-law" used frequently to refer to the family of a life partner, whether legally married or not, and find such use perfectly unobjectionable and widely understood.

Answer (score 7):

*Brother-in-law* is the usual term.