# My sister's husband's parents in relation to me

Tags: kinship-terms, interpersonal-relations

I have a sister. What are her husband's parents to me (i.e. her parents in-law)?

Comment: As far as I know we don't have a better term than 'my sister's parents-in-law'.  You might be interested in this essay - it's not precisely what you want but it might give a lead http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/08/naming-of-cousins/

Comment: The Chinese may have a word for that.  If they don't, I doubt any other language does.

Comment: related: [What is the relationship name of my wife's brother to me?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13346/what-is-the-relationship-name-of-my-wifes-brother-to-me) and [Name for the relationship of wife’s sister’s husband](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83834/name-for-the-relationship-of-wife-s-sister-s-husband)

Comment: An explanation for the lexical gap in the English language: [Paucity of words for relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships)

Comment: Why the downvotes?  OK, no research shown...well the OP is aware of "parents in-law". Question unclear? No. It's very clear. It's not  a duplicate. Lack of effort? Yes. But give the newcomer a chance!

Comment: In English, the word for people who are not related to you is ***unrelated***.

Comment: @tchrist: LOL, I think your comment goes deeper than you maybe intended :) I had exactly the same feeling: "why the hell should we have a *term* for something which we do not feel as a *notion*"? Apparently, this is culturally dependent.
The same as Mari-Lou A, I do not think that the OP deserves downvotes for this question.
And it may be very interesting - if the OP knows - to put here an example of a language which has developed a word for such an "unrelated relationship" :)

Comment: Realated (possible dupe): [What is the term for my son's father/mother in law?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/215168/8019).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sister is married, her husband is your *brother-in-law*, when referring to his parents you can say: my **brother-in-law's parents**

Google Books has  91 hits for *brother-in-law's parents*

> As friends and family visited my sister with offers of food, money and emotional support.**My brother-in-law's parents**, brother, sister, and extended family came from Brooklyn, Pennsylvania, Long Island and Florida.
> <sub><sup>[Newyorkseptembereleventwothousandone](https://books.google.it/books?id=IpTaAAAAMAAJ&q=%22brother-in-law%27s%20parents%22&dq=%22brother-in-law%27s%20parents%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwADgUahUKEwi9yMSIifPHAhXJPRoKHYCgACE)</sup></sub>

Your sister is married and her husband's parents are **her** **[in-laws](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-laws)**.
Her husband's mother is her *[mother-in-law](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mother-in-law)*, while his father is her *[father-in-law](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/father-in-law)*. Consequently, you could also call them:  *my sister's parents-in-laws.*

But astonishingly, Google Books has no results for *[sister's parents-in-laws](https://www.google.it/search?q=brother-in-law%27s%20parents&oq=brother-in-law%27s%20parents&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22sister%27s%20parents-in-laws%22)*.

Instead, the shortened *in-laws* is preferred. The expression: **sister's in-laws** is reported [363 times](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22sister%27s+in-laws%22&tbm=bks&start=40) by Google Books.

> My **sister's in-laws** did not live in Nanjing, and this created a housing problem. Most new couples could not get a housing unit from the government. They had to live with one or the other's parents for a while, usually the husband's.
> <sub><sup>[Thirty Years in a Red House: A Memoir of Childhood and Youth in Communist China](https://books.google.it/books?id=BfNV89yevq0C&pg=PA149&dq=%22sister%27s%20in-laws%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI8abhho7zxwIVibUUCh1yaQDr#v=onepage&q=%22sister%27s%20in-laws%22&f=false)</sup></sub>
>
> All of the couple's siblings live here - as well as her **sister's in-laws**, his sister's in-laws, and many cousins. They are an extended family that would do any Midwestern town proud,...
> <sub><sup>Calling Arizona Home</sup></sub>

Comment: I answered this question because 1) I couldn't find a duplicate. 2) there is a kinship expression. 3) the suggested answer in the comment section although technically correct, is not the most common.