# Word for parents of your child's partner

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

There are words for relationships obtained by marriage or partnership of family members: xxx-in-law. But, surprisingly, there is no word (that I know of) for the parents of your child's partner. **Or is there? Or did we forget it?**

I wish there was a word for it (also in Dutch, my native language), because it is always hard to describe this common relationship concisely.

For who is interested: the Malay language has **besan**: *relationship between parents whose children are married to each other*.

Comment: The parents of my son's wife.  They are: *my son's in-laws*.  I don't know a shorter name.

Comment: [Quntae and qunba](http://books.google.com/books?id=Zr783379T4UC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq="parents+of+child's+spouse") - Google Books shows words for this in an African language.

Comment: Not every single concept can be expressed by a single word. It's not that surprising that this particular concept has no word for it.

Comment: I agree with your first statement, but why would such a common concept not have a word for it? We should invent one! :)

Comment: If you're in a context where *"our"* clearly means yourself and your spouse, it's unlikely anyone would misunderstand if you referred to them as *"our in-laws"*.

Comment: See [Paucity of words for relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'd love to say _besan_, but that probably would not help any smooth communication. Yours is second best.

Comment: @Mitch, hmmm, interesting phenomenon.

Comment: I do like Besan.

Comment: What Mr. Shiny and New said. It's interesting that many people complain about the fact that English has so many words, and that lots of people complain that we *don't* have "single words" for certain things (in particular here, non-genetic relationships). I don't mind at all not having a single word for something I can easily describe using a few others. If I *did* have a single word, then I'd have to worry about whether I could still use it if the "linking" married children got divorced. Sounds like a lot of trouble to me.

Comment: I’ve often referred to my daughters in-laws as the out-laws 

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132129/is-there-a-word-meaning-my-childs-spouses-parents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is none that I've ever heard.  I would simply use *son's/daughter's [in-laws](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in-laws)*.

Comment: Yes, and I do. It always seems to require some two-stage expression. One word would be easier and more elegant. And less _detached_.

Comment: Of course, _no, there isn't_ would be a valid answer. I wait a while to see what will come across.