# Is there a word meaning "my child's spouse's parents"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, vocabulary, kinship-terms

If I am introducing someone to my daughter's husband's parents can I say "Hi, I'd like to you meet my ***_*__**". In-laws would not work here because they are my child's in-laws not my own. Is there a word for this relationship?

Comment: I'd like you to meet my daughter's in-laws or my son in-laws parents.

Comment: skullpatrol's comment handles the introduction the best, IMO, since it describes *your* relation to your daughter's husband (he's your son-in-law) and *his* relationship to his parents.  It seems the most respectful of the elders of the group being introduced which I believe is considered good etiquette.

Comment: Of the two, I think I prefer “son-in-law's parents,” as the other may sound confusingly like “daughters-in-law” in conversation. But both are good – they came to my mind also when working up my answer.

Comment: In Britain, with our deep sense of irony, we sometimes refer to 'the in-laws and the out-laws'. But I wouldn't try that unless you know them really well!

Comment: If consuegros more or less translates as co-in-laws, then I think co-in-laws is the best term in English.

Comment: Doesn't "in-laws" still work? You wouldn't say they are 'my in-laws' but you might say 'the in-laws' or just 'in-laws'. For example, "We're having in-laws over for dinner, my daughter's husband's parents."

Comment: like uncle and aunt, which can be blood relatives or in-laws, I would be tempted to say e.g. "brother in law" or "sister in law" but I'm almost sure that would be wrong!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wiktionary attests a specific term for the relationship you describe: [**co-parents-in-law.**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-parents-in-law) However, it recommends simply using **in-law** in conversation:

> Rare in conversation, the generic “in-laws” is generally used, with context left to disambiguate. Once grandchildren are born, the term co-grandparents may be used if the focus is on the relationship through the grandchildren rather than though the married couple.

While we most often use [*in-law*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in-law) to refer to the blood relatives of your own spouse, or sometimes the spouses of your blood relatives, you can also use it for other **relatives by marriage.** For example, a *brother-in-law* is your spouse’s brother or your sibling’s husband, and your *in-laws* are your spouse’s family, but an *in-law* could be a more distant relation, in context.

If that's unsatisfactory, you can simply say **my daughter’s in-laws** or **my son-in-law’s parents.** Indeed, that may be the simplest and clearest way to introduce them.

On a related note: Relationship through marriage is called [*affinity,*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_%28law%29) as opposed to [*consanguinuity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consanguinity) for blood relations. You can call a relative by marriage *affinal kin,* although I doubt it’d be understood by anyone but a genealogist or a practitioner of family law.

Comment: If your child has children, "co-grandparents" will do.

Answer (score 6):

Although they are Greek words, *sympatheroi* (plural), *sympathera* (feminine singular) and *sympatheros* (masculine singular) could work well.  The words mean "my child's parent(s)-in-law", literally "co-parent(s)".  They are used in the first person (Hello, Sympathera!) as well as the third person.

*Sympatheroi*  has a niche use in the Uniform Parish Regulations of the Greek Orthodox Church in America:

"Relatives are not permitted to serve on the parish council at the same time.  *Relatives* means spouses, parents and children, siblings, and sympatheroi."

English has *symphony*, but hasn't yet adopted *sympatheroi*. The reason is probably cultural: English-speaking societies did not place a high value on this relationship, so had no need for a special word for it.

Comment: +1 for the word sympatheroi and for the cultural observation about this relationship not having much value.

Answer (score 5):

While not English, there is a term from Yiddish that is injected into sentences otherwise in English by many, especially in communities with significant Jewish populations - **[machatunim](http://www.interfaithfamily.com/relationships/grandparenting/Thoughts_on_Being_a_Bubbie.shtml)** (or *mechatunim*, it being a transliteration with a good deal of regional dialectic diversity).

> There is no English word for the Yiddish machatunim; in Spanish it is *consuegros* and means "co-in-laws." The parents of the people my children have married are my machatunim.

Machatunim is actually derived from Hebrew. It's plural, referring to both in-laws.

Comment: I actually knew that word, I wrote this question looking for the English equivalent. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would say your son's/daughter's father-in-law/mother-in-law.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing already the word in Spanish and Yiddish, I've suggested *cross-laws* for English. Maybe if everyone on ELU adopts it…