# Relation between parent of son with his father or mother in-law?

Tags: kinship-terms

Is there a word for the relation between the parents and parents-in-law of a child?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132129/is-there-a-word-meaning-my-childs-spouses-parents)?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, by the way

Answer (score 1):

There's no term specific to this relationship, they're just included in the general term *in-laws*, which encompasses any pair of people who become related due to marriage of close relatives of each.

For example, in the 60's there was an American TV show called [The Mothers-in-Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mothers-in-Law), about two friends who became in-laws when their children got married. And there have been two movies called *The In-Laws* ([1979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_In-Laws_(1979_film)), [2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_In-Laws_(2003_film))), about two men who meet when their children become engaged and then get involved in a comedic adventure together (one of them is a CIA agent).

Comment: [Co-parents-in-law](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/132129/94324)

Comment: As mentioned there, that term is not commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then yes there is.

They are in-laws; that is, depending on the two parties' gender, they are sisters-in-law or brothers-in-law.

[image: Example Family Tree]

Using the example above:

- Homer is Jackeline's son-in-law; Jackeline is Homer's mother-in-law.
- Selma is Homer's sister-in-law; Homer is Selma's brother-in-law.

Comment: What about Herb & Marge ? Homer & Patty ? Brother-in-law and Sister-in-law. Atleast in India, we do not refer to Abraham & Clancy as Brother-in-law or Mona & Jackeline as Sister-in-law. When forced, we may say "We visited my Sons In-laws" or "We met my Daughters In-laws". I see that OP is Indian. We have some words in Indian languages which loosely mean "relatives" which is assumed to mean "relatives by marriage".

Comment: Not addressing the question.

Comment: I think the question is asking for the relation between Abraham/Mona and Clancy/Jackeline.

Comment: @Barmar It's actually very difficult to understand what the OP is after.

Comment: @Mitch I was actually unsure about that. Thanks for picking up on that.

Comment: @DogLover I think it's pretty clear: "between the parents and parents-in-law of a child". The child is Homer, his parents are Abraham and Mona, and his parents-in-law are Clancy and Jackeline. The question never mentions siblings.