# What is the relationship name of my sibling-in-law's sibling to me?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, kinship-terms

For example:

1. I have a sister named Charlotte.
2. Charlotte is married to Martin.
3. Martin has a brother named William.

Martin is my brother-in-law, but what is William to me?

Comment: Maybe ask at [genealogy.se]?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no commonly used name for that connection. Normally, you would say "my brother in law's brother". If you and William are very close, I suppose you could call him "my brother in law" in casual conversation, or just "a friend".

Comment: Just say "brother-in-law" unless there is some reason that a more precise relationship is needed.

Comment: Smells like a duplicate, but I don't have time to search for it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have been told on *Genealogy & Family History*, there is no "technical term" for the relationship you describe.

In most areas of language you select the words used to suit the purpose you wish to achieve. If my sister's husband has two brothers, then

- the one in jail is **her** brother-in-law.
- the famous rock star is **related to me** by marriage, almost a brother.