# Are there specific words for the siblings of my brother-in-law (or s.i.l.)?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Having a conversation this weekend, and this came up. Naively, I'd be inclined to simply label the brother of my brother-in-law a brother-in-law as well, since we've joined the families in a sense.

Specifically, my wife's sister's husband has two sisters. I call him my b.i.l., would they be s.i.l. by extension? Is this acceptable usage, or must I trod laboriously through the above description every time I describe the relationship?

Comment: What language do you speak natively?

Comment: Related question, [Name for the relationship of wife’s sister’s husband](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83834/name-for-the-relationship-of-wife-s-sister-s-husband).

Comment: It depends on the family and its customary usage.  (In ours, it's "that idiot.")  Otherwise, generic "brother in law" seems to be sufficient to get into the bratwurst queue at the family picnic.

Comment: Because we had kids, we referred to my wife's sister's husband's sister as "*Aunt* Cindy" for convenience.

Comment: I speak American English natively.

Comment: Jim, that might work, but my children have no relationship with the person in question, so it would be strange when speaking to other relatives/acquaintances.

Comment: Related: http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/seeking-english-term-for-relationship-between-two-members-of-extended-family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One rarely used word for this is [co-brother-in-law](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/co-brother-in-law)

Comment: An uncommon secondary usage of this term... but I suppose it'll have to do unless we get a better answer.