# Relation name for my wife's sister's son's wife

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

What is the relation name for my wife's sister's son's wife?

Comment: My nephew's wife?  (Or if you want to be stuffy about it - my nephew-in-law's wife). :-)

Comment: English doesn't have specific names for most possible relations. You have to stack up the basic ones.

Comment: "My sister-in-law's daughter-in-law"

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would say *niece-in-law*, but others would say there is no relation at all. See *[Paucity of words for relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/)*.

Comment: Thanks for these good answers.  I like simplicity.  I think I would feel most comfortable introducing her (or thinking of her) as my nephew's wife.

Comment: I'm with you Doug.  I actually attended a family photo shoot where someone insisted on getting a group picture of only those related by blood.  SMH. :-)

Comment: Almost a duplicate of: [What do you call your nephew's wife?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208103/what-do-you-call-your-nephews-wife)

Comment: @DougFinley 'nephew's wife' would be misleading because you wife's sister's son is not _your_ nephew. Your wife's siblings are in-laws and not your sisters/brothers, so their children cannot be your niece or nephew. Of course, they are in a niece/nephew-like relationship, so informally you might refer to them as niece/nephew, just like they may cal you informally 'uncle' as some male relative in their parent's generation. But usual rules of kinship in English don't have a single or simple word for this relation.

Answer (score 1):

So here's Bob, a married man whose wife Norma has a sister Ellen.

Ellen is Bob's **sister-in-law**.  Cool.

Ellen's son, Phil, is Norma's and Bob's **nephew**; they are his **aunt** and **uncle**.

Phil gets married to Kim.  Kim is Ellen's **daughter-in-law**, and Bob's and Norma's **niece**.  Forget the "in-law" construct; it's clumsy.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, can you please add sources to your answer to substantiate your claim. You can also have a look at the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers. Especially a reference supporting the referring to a such a person as a niece would be great.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, call her your niece. If, for some reason, you are inquired as to which side of the family she belongs, then feel free to go into detail.