# Non-related cousin?

Tags: kinship-terms

I was wondering what the official term for the relationship described below is.

So My Grandparents D & F had two sons: T & E. T is my father. E married L and had three kids: P, E, & A which are my cousins.

Now L has a sister S (P,E, & A's Aunt) who has two kids C & B (P, E. & A's Cousin).

Now what is the official term for C & B in relation to me?

Comment: POB.  Friends, acquaintances, pals or simply your cousins' cousins.

Comment: Do you have a word for this in your native language, or are you just wondering what it is in English? [English doesn't have many relation words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships).

Comment: Im just wondering for family history reasons

Comment: I don’t know of _any_ language (not even Chinese, which has a _very_ large inventory of relation terms) that has a word for your father’s brother’s wife’s sister’s children.

Answer (score 1):

They are your cousins' cousins.

An English-speaking person wouldn't confuse this for a simpler relationship for which a single word or fixed phrase existed because (except where we want to avoid an ambiguity) we tend to select a formulaic word or phrase in preference to a less formulaic one for family relationships. In support of this, consider "brother" vs. "parents' son". "brother in law" vs. "wife's brother", etc. Thus if we see an unformulaic phrase like "cousins' cousin" we would guess it wasn't a circumlocution that referred to a cousin or sister or anything else that it could technically be.

Answer (score 0):

C & B aren't related to you (by blood), so there isn't a relation word in English for this. We don't say “cousins-in-law”, generally. (Actually, this wouldn't work because cousin-in-law would be taken to mean the spouse of your cousin.)

The best you could do to describe them is to say they are *your cousins’ cousins* or perhaps more precisely, your *aunt's niece and nephew*. (Adjusting for gender/quantity as required.)

Answer (score -1):

If I read your example correctly, your relation would be "cousins once removed".

I base it on the following resource: [link to Wikipedia "Cousin" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin)

As you can see, many different names for relations with cousins exist.

**Edit** It appears I was wrong in my interpretation of your example. I'm not aware of the correct answer as of now, I'm still looking further.

Leaving the answer up for now, to at least provide the link to the best resource I've been able to find up until now.

Comment: It sounds like this would be right but it isn't. A cousin once removed is related by blood, but the example relation in the OP is not.

Comment: I'm afraid not - being "once removed" means (as the Wikipedia article says) that you're one step up or down through the generations, which in this example they aren't.

Comment: Checked the page further, adjusting answer now.

Answer (score -1):

**Cousins by marriage**

is the term used for this in English.  Hyphens if you prefer.

(Note - I may have misunderstood your tree given there; even if these guys are not, precisely, cousins-by-marriage, it's likely a useful phrase in your endeavour, and about the only other term at hand in the field.)

BTW I (think!) they are your

> in-laws's cousins

-- is that right?  (And hence - I think! - cousins-by-marriage.)