# What is a term for the family unit led by an aunt or uncle?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I need this word rather frequently in conversation and it bothers me that I don't know it. This word is the name of the family unit belonging to an uncle or aunt, or both. Similarly, the word for the family unit that I belong to is my immediate family.

- Here is some context/an example:

I'm visiting my grandparents and _____ in Honolulu.

I realize that I can say "uncle's family" but that seems a bit tedious (not that much though). Most of my desire to know this word is now curiosity.

So please, calm my curiosity and possibly that of others; any and every comment is appreciated!

Comment: Compared to _some_ languages, English has quite a poor vocabulary when it comes to family relationships. It doesn't even have separate words for older sister vs younger sister, or "brother of my father" vs "brother of my mother". It even lacks a word for "immediate family" unless you count _household_. I think the most concise you can get is indeed _your uncle's family_. This will preclude the extended family, since that would make no sense; you are part of that extended family. So it will be understood you visit your uncle, his wife and their children.

Comment: If you look through [tag:kinship-terms], you'll find the usual answer to *Is there an English word for X family member?* is either *cousin* or *no*. See *[Paucity of words for relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616)* for a treatment.

Comment: Your cousins are your Uncle's children. It is these people who are the same *generation* as you, so **cousins** is English shorthand for all your Uncle's family. This simply an epexegesis of @Oldbag 's first answer answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at it from the view of your contemporaries and say, "I'll be visiting my **cousins**"

However, this still leaves the question of whether they are relations of your father or your mother. To include grandparents, aunts, uncles and cousins (and clarify) you could say:

**"I'll be visiting my mother's/father's *side of the family*"** or 'my mother's/father's ***kin***'.