# Is there a word for a younger aunt or uncle?

Tags: kinship-terms

A maternal uncle is your mother's brother. What's the term for an uncle that is younger than you, or a niece/nephew that's older?

Comment: No there is not, and the answer by @Josh61 is factually correct.

Comment: Of interest: *[Paucity of words for relationships](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616)*

Answer (score 26):

*An **[uncle](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/uncle)** or an aunt*   who are younger than their nieces or nephews are called ***uncle*** and ***aunt***. The terms are not based on age but on parental relationships:

> - the ​brother of someone's ​mother or ​father, or the ​husband of someone's ​aunt or uncle:

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Not sure why someone is downvoting here. Family relations are not based on age, they're based on lineage. For example, if your mother remarries someone who is younger than you, he is still your step-father, no matter his age.

Comment: @NeMo - I tried to explain why, rather than simply say 'no'. No sarcasm on my part.

Comment: @NeMo - what do you mean by "that's just the internet for you"?

Comment: @Josh61 I am as puzzled as you as to why you are being taken to task here. Your answer sounds perfectly urbane, and I see nothing sarcastic in it whatever.

Comment: You could have ' Yuncle and Yaunt"

Comment: @Autistic sounds like a compound which adds you+uncle/aunt. Kind of like y'all :)

Comment: @NeMo I see absolutely no sarcasm in Josh61's answer nor any of his edits. The answer is direct and concise because the StackExchange network of sites are not discussion forums.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That first line could be considered sarcastic if a certain inflection was a implied. I occasionally apply such an inflection when answering (what I consider to be) an obvious question and (I feel that) the person asking should really know the answer. That said, I don't think it applies here, but I am not OP.

Answer (score 12):

In English, relationships are based purely on family lineage and gender of the person. Some languages distinguish on other features, for example:

- In Swedish, mother's mother is *mormor*; father's mother is *farmor*. In English, both are *grandmother*.
- In Thai, elder brother is *pêe*; younger brother is *nóng*. In English, both are *brother*.

So to directly answer your question, such people are simply aunt/uncle/niece/nephew.

In an informal context, many people would refer to an uncle who is approximately their age as a cousin. <s>While it's strictly incorrect, you don't need to explain your family history to everyone you have a casual interaction with.</s> If someone challenges this, they are your "zeroth cousin once removed" (thanks Wossname!)

Comment: zeroth cousin once removed

Answer (score 4):

Let's start off by saying a maternal or paternal uncle  is just called an *[uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle)*. An uncle is also the husband of your mother's or father's sister, so he is is not always consanguineous. And it doesn't matter how old that uncle is or their order of birth in the family, in today's English he is an ‘uncle’.

What's more, there isn't an English diminutive suffix that modifies the noun *uncle*. For example, in Italian a *zio* can be called affectionately *[zietto](http://it.bab.la/dizionario/italiano-inglese/zietto)*, not so in English.

Looking at its [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uncle) we find that *uncle*  is derived from Latin *avunculus* (a mother's brother) and its literal meaning was “little grandfather”, the diminutive of *avus* “grandfather”. Over time it ousted the Middle English terms *eam* (maternal uncle) and *fædera* (paternal uncle).

Therefore, *uncle* originally meant a ‘younger grandfather’, which indicates that 2,600 years ago there wasn't a specific Latin term for this male relative, the Latin speaking population just added a diminutive suffix to a pre-existing word.

The only alternative soluton that comes to mind is ***baby uncle***. This works if the uncle is either younger or closer in age to his nephews and nieces. In fact, younger children are often called *baby sister* and *baby brother* by their elder siblings.

Examples from the net:

> - My mother's baby brother fixed me up for my graduation. I looked real nice. After my graduation, we went out to eat and **my baby uncle** drove me around and made me countless drinks to celebrate.
>     [Source](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAA_LHUx2kC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22my%20baby%20uncle%22&source=bl&ots=yol4sN60xt&sig=NmEUxaXroZ-quGrMOPochi9R4Gc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMlP-MzJ3MAhUnKpoKHSqWAJgQ6AEIUDAO#v=onepage&q=%22my%20baby%20uncle%22&f=false)
> - Most of my family is in Chicago. **My baby uncle** definitely has his points and truth about our family, but I believe we can all get along to a certain extinct. My family really don't have any major issues, it's just that everyone is so petty. I pray every night that my family will grow up ...
>     [Source](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAA_LHUx2kC&pg=PA46&dq=%22my%20baby%20uncle%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWu_Gb4Z3MAhXH1xQKHUEwDqkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22my%20baby%20uncle%22&f=false)

From an article titled **My baby Uncle, Ding**

> - Alfredo Roces is the youngest of the Roces-Reyes brood of nine boys. Too close to his age, we, his older nieces—Sylvia, only six years younger, Ninit and myself, eight years—couldn’t bring ourselves to call him “Uncle” or “Tito,” only “Ding.”
>     [Source](http://lifestyle.inquirer.net/182437/my-baby-uncle-ding)

Likewise, the term aunt is also derived from Latin, and there are no  terms for a mother's sister, a father's sister, or an “aunt-in-law”.

> c. 1300, from Anglo-French *aunte*, Old French *ante* (Modern French *tante*, from a 13c. variant), **from Latin *amita* "paternal aunt"** diminutive of *amma a baby-talk word for "mother" (cognates: Greek *amma* "mother," Old Norse *amma* "grandmother,"...
>   Source: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=aunt)

But contrary to *uncle* there is the diminutive form **auntie** or **aunty** which dates back to 1787. However, it is a term of endearment and is not confined to a person's age or order of birth.

Answer (score 3):

I remember a children's story from my childhood where the protagonist referred to his mother's sister (younger than him) as his "pocket aunt."  Unfortunately I cannot find any attestation on the internet other than one Reddit link, so this usage cannot be considered particularly common.

Comment: I remember that story! About the pocket aunt! My children just got a pocket uncle yesterday lol! Folks have always looked at me weird when I use that term...so I agree...it is def not common

Answer (score 0):

"Younger uncle" is probably your best bet.  Just as you might say "younger brother" to mean a brother who is younger than yourself (as opposed to a brother who is younger than your other brother).

There are languages (e.g. Chinese), where you use a separate word for the same genetic association based on age (e.g. 妹妹 vs 姐姐), but English does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

"Younger uncle", as others have suggested, would more probably convey that of your two uncles, he's the younger. I would not expect it to be interpreted relative to yourself.

I've known several cases of this, and they've always been introduced in a full sentence, like "He's actually my uncle, even though he's younger than me".