# Relationship name my wife's sister's son

Tags: kinship-terms

What is the relationship name for my wife's sister's son? My wife has a sister who has a son. Would it be called nephew in law?

Comment: People usually call their aunt's husband their uncle, so I would just call him your nephew - or your wife's nephew if you need to be specific.

Comment: I think we have a canonical post based on this stuff? Maybe meta?

Comment: Related: [**Paucity of words for relationships**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships)

Comment: also [What is the relationship name of my wife's father's sister's son to me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/523438/) and [What is the English word for husband of the daughter of my brother?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/393903/what-is-the-english-word-for-husband-of-the-daughter-of-my-brother)

Comment: I'd avoid using the genitive possessive form twice, especially in speech, it would be slightly confusing for the listener:  Instead say: My **sister-in-law's son**