# Is there a proper term for an ex-husband of your mother when you are born from her second marriage?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, kinship-terms

My mother was married before I was born, then got divorced, married my father, and had me. Is there a term for my familial relationship to my mothers ex-husband?

Comment: He's "your mother's ex-husband".... there isn't a more specific term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific. It's asking for a term which almost certainly is too specific to exist.

Comment: @AndyT “Too specific to exist”? This is an extremely common situation which millions of people are in. If Aimee had been a child of the first marriage, then her mother’s second husband would almost certainly have been her **stepfather**. The fact that she happens to be a child of the first marriage doesn’t make this any more specific than the concept of stepparents.

Comment: "My mother's ex" is what you'd hear; expand "ex" to "ex-husband" and that's about it in my experience.  Alternatively, consult "Miss Manners".

Comment: "my mother's first husband" actually more objective, ignoring the question how the marriage ended.

Comment: It's not "too specific to exist;" however, the English language doesn't have the complex terms for extended family that some others do. And we have no word for this relationship.

Comment: @Xanne Why do you say "more" objective? The only difference to me between "ex" and "first" is that a "first husband" may have died to end the marriage, while an "ex" husband signifies the relationship ended willfully.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai That seems like an important distinction to me--"first husband" doesn't convey how the marriage ended. :)

Comment: @Xanne Which in this case, doesn't seem appropriate, so I was curious why you recommended "first" over "ex"?

Comment: Perpetually crosslinked: *[Paucity of words for relationships](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616)*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because English has no single word for this relationship.