# Relationship between grandparents

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, interpersonal-relations

Is there a word in English that refers to the relationship between the maternal and paternal grandparents of a child? I've been searching for years and would appreciate any possibilities. Thanks.

Comment: a word in ANY language?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could possibly add what words, if any, you have come across that do not fit? Include some of your research to avoid confusion.

Comment: closely related:[Paucity of words for relationships](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships)

Answer (score 3):

A Yiddish word that has crept into the English of American Jews and those who live in heavily Jewish settings is **machutonim**.  (That "u" can be an "a" or "o" also, by the way.) That literally means the relationship between the parents of one spouse and those of the other.  The best we can do in English is **in-laws**, which can be clear in context:  We're spending Thanksgiving with our in-laws, so none of us have to go without seeing the grandkids.

The article below goes into more depth, elaborating on English's strengths and weaknesses in describing familial relationships.

http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2015/12/09/machatunim_co_in_laws_english_needs_a_word_for_the_relationship_between.html

Comment: machutonim sounds like one of the transuranic elements.

Comment: Thanks, in our case--yup, the parents of our grandchildren are married to each other. It's almost an exception these days! It is the closest I have seen. My daughter-in-law is a Pacific Islander, and even coming from that culture where family is a strong bond, there is no word. Thanks again.