# Is there a term for my Grandparent's Cousin? As in, "My grandparent's cousin is my _____"

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Just doing some family research, and I came across a relative we'll call "Bob". I'm looking for a term to be able to easily refer to my relation to Bob, like "Bob is my Grand-Uncle" or something similar.

**He is the Cousin of my Grandfather, and I'm wondering if there's a specific kinship term for him.**

Comment: It would be "(distant) cousin".

Comment: There's [an excellent summary of kinship terms here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/394304/4972). From the diagram one can read of directly that the answer is: __first cousin twice removed__

Comment: @Mitch The diagram is helpful but I would add that those in green are poorly understood and rarely used.

Comment: @Greybeard agreed.

Answer (score 0):

Amended answer. Please ignore what I wrote earlier. I confusedly gave the relationship with Bob's father.

Were Bob your father's cousin, he would be your "cousin-once-removed".

**As he is your grandfather's cousin, he is your "cousin-twice-removed".**

Comment: @KannE I do apologise. I was thinking of the relationship with Bob's father. I will amend my answer.

Comment: Wikipedia's [page on cousins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin) has a lot of information on these relationships.

Comment: First cousin, twice removed. The _first_ is important to specify a grandfather's cousin.

Comment: @StuartF Yes. That is a good page.