# Word for sibling's sibling-in-law?

Tags: kinship-terms, interpersonal-relations

Imagine this scenario:

- Amy and Brent are sister and brother.
- Clive and Derek are brothers.
- Amy marries Clive.
- Derek is therefore Amy's brother-in-law.
- Brent is also Clive's brother-in-law.
- Derek and Brent are _________?

Are they also brothers-in-law?

Is there a term for this?

If there is no specific term, how could I describe their relationship?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships?rq=1 Derek is Brent's sister's brother-in-law, or his brother-in-law's brother.

Comment: English doesn't have a specific word. They might describe **themselves** as brothers-in-law, especially if the four are all close friends. Otherwise, Derek will simply call Brent "my brother's brother-in-law" (as I do with my brother's sisters-in-law).

Comment: They're relatives.