# Name for the relationship of my wife's father's sister's son to me?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

What is the name for the relationship of my wife's father's sister's son to me?

Comment: Sounds like a _cousin in law_ but I'm not sure that's a real thing.

Comment: Probably covered at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51616/paucity-of-words-for-relationships/51618

Comment: Your wife's cousin. That's how I refer to just such a person.

Comment: You aren't related to that person; your wife is.

Answer (score 6):

He is your wife's cousin. This could further be shortened to "cousin-in-law", but that is ambiguous: it fails to say whether the person is your wife's cousin or your cousin's spouse. So I would recommend saying "wife's cousin".

Comment: *Cousin-in-law* works fine if the exact relationship isn't important.

Comment: In the US, I have never ever *heard* anyone actually use the word *cousin-in-law* though I've seen it in books about genealogy.  It would be far more likely for a speaker of American English to say "my wife's cousin".

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend usually referring to such person as your **cousin** if you are so inclined. Though the word *cousin* often refers to first cousins, it stands in for more distant cousins often as well. It feels natural enough to extend it without adornment to relatives by marriage, just as you would call your father's brother's wife your *aunt*.

You could be more specific if you choose, calling someone your **cousin by marriage** (probably not natural on a form), your **cousin-in-law**, or (even more specific) your **spouse's cousin**.

Answer (score -2):

Brother-in-law.
Your wife’s father is your father-in-law.
His sister’s son is your wife’s cousin.
So he is your brother-in-law.

Comment: Your wife's brother is your brother-in-law. Your wife's cousin is not.

Comment: @PeterShor what about "cousin brother-in-law"?

Comment: @SPatel - No, that doesn't make sense. *Cousin-in-law* is okay if you want to use an *X-in-law* formulation, but *brother* doesn't apply at all.